# Best In Place: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 3) (ArgumentError) with Action_view ' Initialize '

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I recently upgraded Rails app 4.1 to 6.1 and I got this error shown below:

```rb
 rake aborted!
 ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 3)
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.1.4.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:230:in `initialize'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/best_in_place-3.1.1/lib/best_in_place/railtie.rb:7:in `new'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/best_in_place-3.1.1/lib/best_in_place/railtie.rb:7:in `block in 
 <class:Railtie>'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:68:in 
 `block in execute_hook'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in 
 `with_execution_control'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in 
 `execute_hook'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in 
 `block in run_load_hooks'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in 
 `each'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in 
 `run_load_hooks'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:140:in `block 
 in <module:Finisher>'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in 
 run_initializers'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in 
 `run_initializers'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
 /usr/src/app/config/environment.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in 
 `block in require'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in 
 `load_dependency'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in 
 `require'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in 
 `require_environment!'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:533:in `block in 
 run_tasks_blocks'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
 Tasks: TOP => resque:work => resque:preload => resque:setup => environment
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

when I comment the gem best_in_place error goes out but this gem is used in the app that why it gives an error at localhost 3000 that why I comment out, again and again, same error occurs if any one have solution so give answers otherwise answer mail to santu.essence@gmail.com

Comment: What do you mean by 'when I comment the gem best_in_place' -- do you mean `bundle remove` it / remove it from Gemfile file?

Comment: Did you check compatibility of the best_in_place gem with your Rails version?

Comment: comment gem means remove it from gemfile

Comment: and i have already checked compatiblity of gem with my rails version.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [best_in_placce](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) github page:

> NB: For Rails >= 6.1 you can install the gem from this repository with:
>
> gem "best_in_place", git: "https://github.com/mmotherwell/best_in_place"

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer, vote up.

Comment: I am not able to vote up because we need 15 reputations and currently I have not